# Creating two concatenated arrays from a generator

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation, map-function

Consider the following example in Python 2.7. We have an arbitrary function `f()` that returns two 1-dimensional numpy arrays. Note that in general `f()` may returns arrays of different size and that the size may depend on the input.

Now we would like to call `map` on `f()` and concatenate the results into two separate new arrays.

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return np.arange(x),np.ones(x,dtype=int)   

inputs = np.arange(1,10)
result = map(f,inputs)
x = np.concatenate([i[0] for i in result]) 
y = np.concatenate([i[1] for i in result])
```

This gives the intended result. However, since result may take up much memory, it may be preferable to use a generator by calling `imap` instead of `map`.

```
from itertools import imap
result = imap(f,inputs)
x = np.concatenate([i[0] for i in result]) 
y = np.concatenate([i[1] for i in result])
```

However, this gives an error because the generator is empty at the point where we calculate `y`.

Is there a way to use the generator only once and still create these two concatenated arrays? I'm looking for a solution without a for loop, since it is rather inefficient to repeatedly concatenate/append arrays.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that `i[0]` and `i[1]` can have different shapes?

Comment: @SergeiLebedev In general, yes. In my example they have the same shape.

Comment: I don't see the benefit of using a generator for `result`. You still build up two lists of the same size as `result` for the `np.concatenate` call. So, if having two lists is acceptable, you can just iterate over `result` in a for-loop and update the lists simultaneously.

Comment: @SergeiLebedev I want to use this in a situation where the size of result is close to my memory limit.

Comment: Do you know the sizes of `x` and `y`?

Comment: @SergeiLebedev Unfortunately, I don't know the sizes in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to use the generator only once and still create these two concatenated arrays?

Yes, a generator can be cloned with [`tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee):

```
import itertools
a, b = itertools.tee(result)

x = np.concatenate([i[0] for i in a]) 
y = np.concatenate([i[1] for i in b])
```

---

However, using `tee` does not help with the memory usage in your case. The above solution would require 5 N memory to run:

- N for caching the generator inside `tee`,
- 2 N for the list comprehensions inside `np.concatenate` calls,
- 2 N for the concatenated arrays.

Clearly, we could do better by dropping the `tee`:

```
x_acc = []
y_acc = []
for x_i, y_i in result:
    x_acc.append(x_i)
    y_acc.append(y_i)

x = np.concatenate(x_acc)
y = np.concatenate(y_acc)
```

This shaved off one more N, leaving 4 N. Going further means dropping the intermediate lists and preallocating `x` and `y`. Note, that you needn't know the *exact* sizes of the arrays, only the upper bounds:

```
x = np.empty(capacity)
y = np.empty(capacity)
right = 0
for x_i, y_i in result:
    left = right
    right += len(x_i)  # == len(y_i)  
    x[left:right] = x_i
    y[left:right] = y_i

x = x[:right].copy()
y = y[:right].copy()
```

In fact, you don't even need an upper bound. Just ensure that `x` and `y` are big enough to accommodate the new item:

```
for x_i, y_i in result:
    # ...
    if right >= len(x):
        # It would be slightly trickier for >1D, but the idea
        # remains the same: alter the 0-the dimension to fit 
        # the new item.
        new_capacity = max(right, len(x)) * 1.5
        x = x.resize(new_capacity)
        y = y.resize(new_capacity)
```